# Pass ImageSource to another page as parameter

Tags: shell, maui, imagesource

I tried to pass an ImageSource object to another page via shell navigation.

When I call

```
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(FullScreenImagePage)}?",
            new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                ["TempImageSource"] = TempPhotoPoint.ExamplePicture
            });
```

I get the following Exception:
System.InvalidCastException: 'Object must implement IConvertible.'

ExamplePicture is of type ImageSource.

The FullScreenImagePage has a viewmodel which contains

```
[QueryProperty(nameof(TempImageSource), nameof(TempImageSource))]
```

and

```
[ObservableProperty] ImageSource tempImageSource;
```

The viewmodel is linked to the page by using BindingContext.
When I pass the TempPhotoPoint object instead, which contains an ImageSource, everything works fine.
How is it possible to pass the ImageSource object only?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why that doesn't work, but you can work around it by implementing method `ApplyQueryAttributes`, as shown in [Process navigation data using a single method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-7.0#process-navigation-data-using-a-single-method).

- Be sure to add `: IQueryAttributable` to your viewmodel class declaration, so Maui knows to use that method.
- In the method, you specify the conversion:

```cs
... class MyViewModel : IQueryAttributable
{
    ...

    public void ApplyQueryAttributes(IDictionary<string, object> query)
    {
        TempImageSource = query["TempImageSource"] as ImageSource;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TempImageSource));

        ... repeat for all other query parameters ...
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks better, but when I try to bind the TempImageSource to an Image component, by this:
<Image x:Name ="Picture"
               Source="{Binding TempImageSource}"
               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
               VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        </Image>
A new error comes up:
System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a closed Stream.'

Answer (score 0):

The reason for both exceptions is the same.
I bound the original ImageSource earlier to an Image. By binding it, the stream is closed. When I try to rebind it in the FullScreenImagePage the closed stream causes the exceptions.
When I do not bind it before, the passed ImageSource can be bound the way I described in my first post.
I'll try to copy the StreamImageSource into a MemoryStream and work with it. When I find a solution for it, i'll post it here.

Comment: As you’ve discovered, an ImageSource can’t be used two places. You’ll have to create two ImageSources.